# how to re-populate draft js with a given text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

so the following function appends the given text to the existing text in the editor, but what I want is to totally replace whatever exists.

```
const sendTextToEditor = (editorState, text) => {
      setEditorState(insertText(editorState, text))}

const insertText = (editorState, text) => {
  const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const currentSelection = editorState.getSelection();
  const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
     currentContent,
     currentSelection,
     text
  );
  const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
     editorState,
     newContent,
     'insert-fragment'
  );

  return EditorState.forceSelection(
     newEditorState,
     newContent.getSelectionAfter()
  )};
```

I have tried to search how to clear the text editor before populating it with the desired text, using `clearEditorContent` from [draftjs-utils](https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-utils)

```
 setEditorState(clearEditorContent(editorState));
```

but it says `clearEditorContent` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that if I can't clear the editor, I can select everything inside and simply replace it
here is how I did it.

```
const sendTextToEditor = (editorState, text) => {
      setEditorState(insertText(editorState, text));
   };

   const insertText = (editorState, text) => {
      const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      //selecting everything in the editor to be replaced
      const firstBlock = currentContent.getFirstBlock()
      const lastBlock = currentContent.getLastBlock()
      const currentSelection = new SelectionState({
         anchorKey: firstBlock.getKey(),
         anchorOffset: 0,
         focusKey: lastBlock.getKey(),
         focusOffset: lastBlock.getLength(),
         hasFocus: true
     })
      
      const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
         currentContent,
         currentSelection,
         text
      );
      const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
         editorState,
         newContent,
         'insert-characters'
      );

      return EditorState.forceSelection(
         newEditorState,
         newContent.getSelectionAfter()
      );
   };
```